# Invoke js function on click browser tab

Tags: javascript

*How to invoking js function on click browser tab?*
I am looking this solution for invoking user when session gets expire.
Not getting any Solution. Please Help.

Comment: Probably something like this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to detect, that the browser tab with your page was clicked, when user was on aother tab, then you can use `window.onfocus`

```
window.onfocus = function() { alert('Browser tab clicked'); };
```