# Is it possible to place a static image on top of the webview in a Cordova applicaiton

Tags: ios, cordova, webview

My case is the following: I have a Cordova application that has to run on iOS. I have to prevent sensitive information from being shown in the app switcher when the app is being in background.

Apple provides this [solution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1838/_index.html) for native applications which doesn't seem to solve my problem, because it doesn't manipulate the web view in any way.

I wonder if I can natively place some static image covering the webview. As I understand the system takes a screenshot of the view right after  the *applicationDidEnterBackground:* method is invoked.

This way the system will take a screenshot of the image I put on top instead of the actual content of the webview.

I'm not an experienced iOS developer and I will appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: You could add a fullscreen div with an appropriate `z-index`, not native, but it'll work. [Detect If Browser Tab Has Focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus) might be useful.

Comment: Thanks, but I have some concerns. Manipulating any web content is asynchronous to the native app lifecycle. So most certainly showing the blank div will not happen on time, or at least I cannot rely on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out apple's solution could fix the problem with a small edit from me.

Instead of implementing

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

I implemented

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Then no matter if you hit the home button once or twice, it will cover the viewcontroller with the blank one just created.

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    UIViewController *blankViewController = [UIViewController new];

    //this is how to attach image
    UIImage *splashImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"some image"];
    blankViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: splashImage];

    // set some transition style
    blankViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;

    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:blankViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```