# Detect session end between tabs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser-tab

I'm developing an AngularJS webapp that can be opened in different tabs, I would like to know which is the best way to detect when the user logs-out in one of these tabs; I'd like to popup a login modal window in the other tabs.
I was thinking to use a server-sent event or track the existence of my server cookie.
I never done something like this, so I'm asking what are the pros and cons about my options or if I missing some other smarter way to do it.

EDIT: on the server I've got ServiceStack (C#) that supports Server-Sent Events out of the box

Answer (score 3):

As you're using [ServiceStack's Server Events](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Server-Events) you can just send a notification when a user logs out.

First you need to detect the User has logged out by implementing the OnLogout [Session or Auth Event](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#session-events), e.g:

```
public class MyAuthEvents : AuthEvents
{
    public IServerEvents ServerEvents { get; set; }

    public override void OnLogout(IRequest httpReq, 
        IAuthSession session, IServiceBase authService) 
    {
        var channel = "home"; //replace with channel tabs are subscribed to
        var msg = "...";
        ServerEvents.NotifyUserId(session.UserAuthId, "cmd.logout", msg, channel);
    }
}
```

Notifying by **UserId** will send the notification to different tabs as well as browsers where the user is logged in. If you only want to send notifications to all tabs in just the 1 browser you can use the `NotifySession(session.Id)` API instead.

To register your AuthEvents Handler with ServiceStack you just need to register it in the IOC, e.g:

```
container.RegisterAs<MyAuthEvents, IAuthEvents>();
```

Then handle the **cmd.logout** notification in your [JavaScript ServerEvents Client](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/JavaScript-Server-Events-Client), e.g:

```
$(source).handleServerEvents({
    handlers: {
        logout: function (msg) {
            //Show AngularJS dialog
            $mdDialog.alert({
                title: 'Attention',
                textContent: msg,
                ok: 'Close'
            });
        },
        //... Other custom handlers
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Server sent events is pretty good way to handle this. Event based handling is good because it saves resources unlike other methods like (checking the existence of cookies), or constant polling of data, or heartbeat type of thing. 
So any method where server can message the client app to work on something(in your case popup a modal informing the logged out session) will do the best. You can also use socket.io which is well designed and can do this easily.

Answer (score 2):

You can check some cookie or session when your tab gets the focus. If you logout in one tab and switch to another, the active tab gets onfocuse event. You can check if some login cookie or session is still there.

[Detect If Browser Tab Has Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus)

I think you have similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

One relatively easy way to go is using SignalR: when the user logs out, send a message to all other sessions of the same user.

Comment: Isn't SignalR a C# (or .NET) specific thing?

Comment: Yes, SignalR is asp.net specific. If other backend is used you can use web sockets to do the same thing. (SignalR uses websockets under the hood if the browser supports it).

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: There is no good way.

The long answer:

There are a lot of ways of 'ending a session', as well as several definitions of what 'ending a session' even means.

Ways to end the session include:

- Closing the tab
- Navigating away
- Closing the browser.
- Force-closing the browser.
- Unplugging the internet
- Changing IP addresses
- Sudden power-off
- Cleaning browser history

There are two solutions commonly used...

- Have the client poll the server every 30-60 seconds to say I'm alive
- Use websockets, which can detect closing.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I was not clear... If I have different tabs and I close one of them the session will "continue" on the others,
I was asking about the explicit user action of "logout".

Comment: Unless you have code there to interrupt the other sessions, they should continue just fine