# how to reload page when i click the browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to reload the page when user click the browser tab

Because when the user pressed the link(for eg : click here),the link will be opened in another tab ,

if they do one r more times means many tabs will be opened with same values,

cause we set a target as _blank

The user change the values in one tab and saved that and closed the tab, after that 
   if the user goes to another tab means its will shown old values only,cause of not reloading

so i need to reload page when i click browser tab

i think now u guys understand my issues ,pls help me

Comment: Consider other options. If you are using .Net you should take a look at SignalR: https://www.asp.net/signalr

Answer (score 1):

You should try to give the target-attribute a name.

e.g:

```
<a href="URL" target="ALPHANUMERIC_NAME">LINK</a>
```

This should result in one single Tab. And you can avoid, that your user sees outdated tabs.

If you prefer to keep this behavior, you have to use Javascript to check if the Tab is focused. Please check this [Detect If Browser Tab Has Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus)

In short words:

```
window.onfocus
```