# Animation Play State Fails to Pause CSS Animation when Users Switch between Tabs

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

In the website I am building, I would like to have some of my animations paused every time the user moves to another tab and have them running again when they come back.
The following code is a simple replication of what I want to achieve.  What I expect is for the red box to stop moving when users move to another tab and pick up where it stops when the user returns.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        @keyframes moving {
            from {
                transform: translateX(0);
            }
            to{
                transform: translate(1000px);
            }
        }
        .box{
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: red;
            animation: moving 5000ms forwards;
        }
        
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <script>
        const box = document.querySelector(".box");
        window.addEventListener("blur",()=>{
            box.style.animationPlayState = "paused"
        })
        window.addEventListener("focus",()=>{
            box.style.animationPlayState = "running"
        }) 
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried switching the `animationPlayState` to `"paused"` on the "blur" event and switch it back to `"running"` on the "focus" event.  So far, I have been getting inconsistent results. While the animation sometimes behaved the way I want, there have also been times when it just cut to the end when the user returns to my tab.
I have also tried the solutions suggested in this question but they didn't work: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892889/pause-resume-css-animations-when-switching-tabs#:~:text=You%20need%20to%20set%20the,to%20blur%20and%20focus%20event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52892889/pause-resume-css-animations-when-switching-tabs#:%7E:text=You%20need%20to%20set%20the,to%20blur%20and%20focus%20event).

Comment: Which browser are you experiencing this issue on? Firefox and Safari have a *bug* of some sort (https://bugzil.la/1881649). But for Chrome I guess the issue would happen only if you never gave focus to the page to begin with. In that case, using *visibilitychange* instead of focus/blur might be preferred, though beware they're not exactly the same, switching to another window group while maintaining the animated tab visible wouldn't trigger *visibilitychange*.

Comment: @Kaiido I was using Chrome. Visibilitychange doesnt work either

Comment: Oh interesting, we indeed need some hack around for CSS tules to be taken into consideration..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Chrome you can achieve this by grabbing the actual [`Animation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation) object and calling its `pause()` method. However, Firefox will actually pause the animation only a few seconds later because they do throttle animation frames (see [Bug 1881649](https://bugzil.la/1881649)) and Safari will act as if it was never paused, because it will wait for the page is actually focused back before pausing the animation.

Anyway, for Chrome, this code should do:

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");
const [anim] = box.getAnimations().filter(({
  animationName
}) => animationName === "moving");
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', (evt) => {
  if (document.visibilityState === "visible") {
    anim.play();
  } else {
    anim.pause();
  }
});
```

```css
@keyframes moving {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(1000px);
  }
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: moving 5000ms forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Another, more hackish solution, still for Chrome only, is to fire a synchronous reflow after we changed the element's style:

```js
const box = document.querySelector(".box");
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", ()=>{
  box.style.animationPlayState = document.visibilityState === "visible" ? "running" : "paused";
  box.offsetWidth;// force a reflow
});
```

```css
@keyframes moving {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(1000px);
  }
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: moving 5000ms forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Note that in both cases, we switched to the `visibilitychange` event, `focus/blur` won't work properly in StackSnippet's `<iframe>`. The main difference between these events is that `blur` will fire even if you switch only to another window group and keep the current tab visible behind.

Comment: It works!!! Thank you very much. You saved me from manually building the animation using Javascript