# How to detect if the user has switched browser tab?

Tags: javascript, angular

If the user switches tab or open other applications, I want to throw an error message

How to do this in JavaScript? (I'm using Angular)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect If Browser Tab Has Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus)

Answer (score 1):

Question already answered here: [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Not specific to Angular but JS.

Comment: I agree, but please, use "flag" option instead of answering

Comment: Actually, there is a 'angular way' of doing this, using [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener)

Comment: @MikeS. That's more 'angular way' of listening for `window` events, I think. Tab focus detection is not framework-specific unless there's a plugin to do that...