# Javascript event on tab activation?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, dom-events

Did I dream I once used a browser event that was triggered by browser tab/window activation? I can't find any such event now. (Or, was that an OS-level event?)

Comment: Possibly, you're thinking about onfocus / onblur
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus)

Comment: @Phil Ah, yes. Thanks. That should work.