# Is it possible to stop javascript from knowing if window/document has focus?

Tags: javascript, lost-focus

Some websites stop working (for example, playing music) if one moves from one tab to another. **Question**: Is it possible for the client to stop this behaviour?

There are multiple ways to check if the current browser tab is focused. One can use `document.hasFocus()` or `window.addEventListener('focus', function)`, for example. The `visibilitychange` or `blur` events aren't cancelable, so `Event.stopPropagation` wouldn't work. But is there any other way to stop their propagation? (For example, could an addon break the way the `blur` event works and not make it dispatch?)

Or is there a way to simulate a tab having focus via the JS console? For example, by toggling a checkbox in the Web Console or by constantly retriggering a `focus` event after the tab loses focus? (Or maybe could tampermonkey force set the read-only `document.visibilityState` always to `visible`?)

---

Regarding the question being closed: This question is not the same as [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active), it's asking from the opposite direction: that question asks how can one detect changes in focus, this one asks how can one avoid that detection

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but first you'll need to find out which mechanism the page uses for detecting focus (there are a few).

Comment: For a simple solution, you can try making a tampermonkey script that makes `document.hasFocus = () => true;` and override `window.AddEventListener` to if the first argument is `"focus"` don't actually register a listener.

Comment: @dippas No, that's the exact opposite of the question asked here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus

Comment: Yes, sites you wish to not perform this action you can write a simple script and inject through console or something like tampermonkey.

Comment: I'd try to scope the function they run and cancel it by over-writing it; if that doesn't work create another event listener to re-enable the function when you go out of focus! :)

Comment: @BGPHiJACK thanks! I think tampermonkey would be the best solution to inject the script as soon as the page starts loading, otherwise changing `addEventListener` and so on would be too late. Ideally, there'd be some `stopPropagation` solution, but I don't think there's a similar thing for this event

Comment: @Samathingamajig that's a good idea! But it'd also have to check for `document.hidden`, `document.visibilityState`, `document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange)` and possibly something else I'm missing. Ideally, there'd be some way to keep dispatching a "focus" event (or to stop propagation of any "blur"), but I don't think there's such a thing

Comment: While it's not a perfect solution, one can [use the browser inspector and remove eventListeners](https://superuser.com/a/1462761/423890)