Simulate Click function with a Delay regardless of tab focus?
I've looked everywhere online, but can't find a straight answer to this specific issue.
Normally, you'd do something like this if you wanted to delay a click:
setTimeout(() => {
    $('.review-more-btn').trigger('click');
}, 1000);

That'll make the browser simulate a click on that button after the page loads, a second later. Great. Works fine.
However, on a browser like Edge or Chrome, if you navigate off of the page (maybe you opened it as a tab and then went off to do other stuff), setTimeout() goes all manner of whack and doesn't always work as intended when you return back to it. A well-known JavaScript issue as old as time.
jQuery's delay() function doesn't work on non-visual functions, so I can't do something like the following as it ignores the delay altogether.
$('.review-more-btn').delay(1000).trigger('click');

Is there any possible way to make sure it always fires off properly regardless of page focus? Thanks.

I suspect this is more of a browser concern than a code concern.  Browsers de-allocate resources for non-visible tabs in a variety of ways to improve performance.  What's the use case here?  Is the click triggered upon returning to the tab?  Is that not sufficient?

@David That's the issue. In theory, yes, it should be triggered upon returning to the tab, but that doesn't always happen in practice, due to a bug with setTimeout. From what I experience, sometimes it doesn't fire at all, as if the function was never executed.

you can make a timeout in a webworker (which is not throttled) and move the reaction code to the worker message handler instead of the setTimeout callback. Since it's so simple, you can use a dataURL as a worker source. search for examples.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus
